# Fields in Formik (validated on Yup) are constantly displaying an error as if they are empty or invalid. find codesandbox-link attached below

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik, yup

```
 const updateCreateFormField = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    
    setCreatForm({
      ...createForm,
      [name]: value,
    })

    console.log({ name, value });
  };
```

//The onChange variable in the fields is updated on the above code. I am unable to find the solution towards making the below fields function properly. I tried using formik's setFieldValue however It didn't work

```
    const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      Name: "",
      Address: "",
      phoneNumber: "",
      Email: "",
    }
  })
```

The below code is the return function:

```
    return (<div className="App">
         
    {updateForm._id && (<div>
      <h2>Update Customer:</h2>
      <Box height={20} />
      <Formik initialValues={formik.initialValues}
        validationSchema={object({
          Name: string().required("Please enter a name").min(3, "Name is too short"),
          Address: string().required("Please enter an address").min(3, "Address is too short"),
          phoneNumber: number().required("Please enter a phone number").min(4, "Phone number is too short"),
          Email: string().required("Please enter an email").email("Invalid email"),
        })}
        onSubmit={(values, formikHelpers) => {
          console.log(values);
          formikHelpers.resetForm();
        }}
      >

        {({ errors, isValid, touched, dirty }) => (
          <Form onSubmit={updateCustomer}>

            <Field name="Name" type="name" as={TextField} variant="outlined" color="primary" label="Name" fullWidth
              onChange={handleUpdateFieldChange}
              value={updateForm.Name}
              error={Boolean(errors.Name) && Boolean(touched.Name)}
              helperText={Boolean(touched.Name) && errors.Name}
            />
            <Box height={14} />
            <Field name="Address" type="Address" as={TextField} variant="outlined" color="primary" label="Address" fullWidth
              onChange={handleUpdateFieldChange}
              value={updateForm.Address}
              error={Boolean(errors.Address) && Boolean(touched.Address)}
              helperText={Boolean(touched.Address) && errors.Address}
            />
            <Box height={14} />
            <Field name="phoneNumber" type="number" as={TextField} variant="outlined" color="primary" label="Phone Number" fullWidth
              error={Boolean(errors.phoneNumber) && Boolean(touched.phoneNumber)}
              helperText={Boolean(touched.phoneNumber) && errors.phoneNumber}
              onChange={handleUpdateFieldChange}
              value={updateForm.phoneNumber}
            />
            <Box height={14} />
            <Field name="Email" type="email" as={TextField} variant="outlined" color="primary" label="Email" fullWidth
              error={Boolean(errors.Email) && Boolean(touched.Email)}
              helperText={Boolean(touched.Email) && errors.Email}
              onChange={handleUpdateFieldChange}
              value={updateForm.Email}
            />
            <Box height={16} />
            <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" size="large" disabled={!dirty || !isValid} >Update Customer</Button>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>)}

    {!updateForm._id && <div>
      <h2>Create Customer:</h2>
      <Box height={20} />
      <Formik initialValues={formik.initialValues}
        validationSchema={object({
          Name: string().required("Please enter a name").min(3, "Name is too short"),
          Address: string().required("Please enter an address").min(3, "Address is too short"),
          phoneNumber: number().required("Please enter a phone number").min(4, "Phone number is too short"),
          Email: string().required("Please enter an email").email("Invalid email"),
        })}
        onSubmit={(values, formikHelpers) => {
          console.log(values);
          formikHelpers.resetForm();
        }}
      >

        {({ setFieldValue, errors, isValid, touched, dirty,handleBlur,handleSubmit}) => (
          <Form onSubmit={createCustomer} >

            <Field as={TextField} name="Name" type="name" variant="outlined" color="primary" label="Name" fullWidth
              onChange={updateCreateFormField} value={createForm.Name}
              error={Boolean(errors.Name) && Boolean(touched.Name)}
              helperText={Boolean(touched.Name) && errors.Name}
            />
            <Box height={14} />
            <Field name="Address" type="Address" as={TextField} variant="outlined" color="primary" label="Address" fullWidth
              error={Boolean(errors.Address) && Boolean(touched.Address)}
              helperText={Boolean(touched.Address) && errors.Address}
              onChange={updateCreateFormField} value={createForm.Address}
            />
            <Box height={14} />
            <Field name="phoneNumber" type="number" as={TextField} variant="outlined" color="primary" label="Phone Number" fullWidth
              error={Boolean(errors.phoneNumber) && Boolean(touched.phoneNumber)}
              helperText={Boolean(touched.phoneNumber) && errors.phoneNumber}
              onChange={updateCreateFormField}
              value={createForm.phoneNumber}
            />
            <Box height={14} />
            <Field name="Email" type="email" as={TextField} variant="outlined" color="primary" label="Email" fullWidth
              error={Boolean(errors.Email) && Boolean(touched.Email)}
              helperText={Boolean(touched.Email) && errors.Email}
              onChange={updateCreateFormField}
              value={createForm.Email}
            />
            <Box height={16} />
            <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" size="large" disabled={!dirty || !isValid} >Create Customer</Button>
          </Form>
        )}


      </Formik>
    </div>}

    <Box height={40} />

  </div>
  )
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-yup-customer-validation-crud-dqco80)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-yup-customer-validation-crud-dqco80 this is the codesandbox link

Comment: Hey Anthony! The Codesandbox seems to be deleted or set on private 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use Formik's `handleChange` event and `values`. You don't need to create custom functions or states to change values.

Working [example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-yup-customer-validation-crud-forked-r04r6d?file=/src/components/App.js)

Also, if you want to have custom function to have inside `onChange` you can use formik's `setFieldValue`.

More information related to formik events https://formik.org/docs/api/formik